# Modifying a logit link in GAM (mgcv)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, gam, mgcv

I am trying to modify the logit link for binomial GAMs in the mgcv package, but I am not having much success. The modified link provided by Ben Bolker below (Method 2 here: https://rpubs.com/bbolker/logregexp) works in GLM, but not GAM. I want to use the code in daily nest survival analyses according to the logistic exposure method described by Shaffer (2004; https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4090416.pdf). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for GLM link:

```
logexp <- function(exposure = 1)
{
    linkfun <- function(mu) qlogis(mu^(1/exposure))
            linkinv <- function(eta)  plogis(eta)^exposure
    logit_mu_eta <- function(eta) {
        ifelse(abs(eta)>30,.Machine$double.eps,
               exp(eta)/(1+exp(eta))^2)
        ## OR .Call(stats:::C_logit_mu_eta, eta, PACKAGE = "stats")
    }
    mu.eta <- function(eta) {       
        exposure * plogis(eta)^(exposure-1) *
            logit_mu_eta(eta)
    }
    valideta <- function(eta) TRUE
    link <- paste("logexp(", deparse(substitute(exposure)), ")",
                   sep="")
    structure(list(linkfun = linkfun, linkinv = linkinv,
                   mu.eta = mu.eta, valideta = valideta, 
                   name = link),
              class = "link-glm")
}
```

I want to include the link in a gam in the form

```
mod<-gam(y~x1 + x2 + s(x3), family=binomial(logexp(df$expos), data=df)
```

Where y = 1 or 0, x variable can be continuous or categorical, and expos = the number of days between observations.

Comment: See this related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793085/custom-link-function-works-for-glm-but-not-mgcv-gam

Comment: Thank you. I have seen the related thread, but I was not able to make it work for me.